# Java: SQL connection

Tags: java

Every time i run this code it shows "error on database". i have been using mysql connector(jdbc).

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MySQLConnection {

    public static Connection conn;

    public static Connection connectDb() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysq1.jdbc.Driver");
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sis_db";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "connect";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error on Database Connection");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: add `e.printStacktrace()` to see what is happend

Comment: Well you could start by displaying the exception... there's likely to be valuable information in there, but you're just ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

As i can see you use package Name `mysql1`with number 1. That must be an lower case letter l

```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: @ASHOKDUMARU You are welcome. If it helps, feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer.